# Sendmail syntax question when upgrading to RH9

Tags: sendmail, mailx

So on our old RH6, RH7 servers we would send out mail for reporting using mailx in our scripts.  Now we are migrating to RH9 and I haven't used s-nail.  I am running the following on the cmd line

echo -e "This is a Test. \nPlease ignore any replication alerts  \n\nThank you  \nTest Team" | s-nail -r "garbage@garbag.com" -s "DB Backup in Progress" -S smtp="mail-sysrelay.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.net:25" "ccap1010@gmail.com"

Using this method I do get the email but I also get a bunch or warning messages.  Is there a way to suppress or set up the smtp correctly?

s-nail: Warning: variable superseded or obsoleted: smtp
s-nail: Obsoletion warning: please do not use *smtp*, instead assign a smtp:// URL to *mta*!
s-nail: Obsoletion warning: Use of old-style credentials, which will vanish in v15!
s-nail:   Please read the manual section "On URL syntax and credential lookup"

really just changed mailx to s-nail in my command line.  I'm thinking i need to do something different with the smtp value but not sure what.

Comment: Have you considered using directly sendmail program for sending simple/trivial US-ASCII emails?